# Tensorflow: Why is tf.case giving me the wrong result?

Tags: python, tensorflow, python-2.x

I'm trying to use `tf.case` (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/case) to conditionally update a Tensor. As shown, I'm trying to update `learning_rate` to `0.01` when `global_step == 2`, and to `0.001` when `global_step == 4`.

However, when `global_step == 2`, I already get `learning_rate = 0.001`. Upon further inspection, it looks like `tf.case` is giving me the wrong result when `global_step == 2` (I get `0.001` instead of `0.01`). This is happening even though the predicate for `0.01` is evaluating to True, and the predicate for `0.001` is evaluating to False.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug?

**TF Version: 1.0.0**

Code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

global_step = tf.Variable(0, dtype=tf.int64)
train_op = tf.assign(global_step, global_step + 1)
learning_rate = tf.Variable(0.1, dtype=tf.float32, name='learning_rate')

# Update the learning_rate tensor conditionally
# When global_step == 2, update to 0.01
# When global_step == 4, update to 0.001
cases = []
case_tensors = []
for step, new_rate in [(2, 0.01), (4, 0.001)]:
    pred = tf.equal(global_step, step)
    fn_tensor = tf.constant(new_rate, dtype=tf.float32)
    cases.append((pred, lambda: fn_tensor))
    case_tensors.append((pred, fn_tensor))
update = tf.case(cases, default=lambda: learning_rate)
updated_learning_rate = tf.assign(learning_rate, update)

print tf.__version__
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for _ in xrange(6):
        print sess.run([global_step, case_tensors, update, updated_learning_rate])
        sess.run(train_op)
```

Results:

```
1.0.0
[0, [(False, 0.0099999998), (False, 0.001)], 0.1, 0.1]
[1, [(False, 0.0099999998), (False, 0.001)], 0.1, 0.1]
[2, [(True, 0.0099999998), (False, 0.001)], 0.001, 0.001]
[3, [(False, 0.0099999998), (False, 0.001)], 0.001, 0.001]
[4, [(False, 0.0099999998), (True, 0.001)], 0.001, 0.001]
[5, [(False, 0.0099999998), (False, 0.001)], 0.001, 0.001]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was answered in https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8776

It turns out that `tf.case` behavior is undefined if, in `fn_tensors`, the lambdas return a tensor that was created outside of the lambda.  The correct usage is to define the lambdas such that they return a newly-created tensor.

According to the linked Github issue, this usage is required because `tf.case` must create the tensor itself in order to hook up the tensor's inputs to the correct branch of the predicate.