# Is it possible to use the output of a classifier model to branch to a different model?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

For example, Model A has an input image and classifies it.  Assume it has an output dimension of 3, e.g. (0, 1, 0).  Based on the output, it then passes the image into Model X, Y, or Z.  Essentially I am looking for a layer to perform this conditional?

Comment: What exactly is a "3-dimensional classifier"? How do you output one?

Comment: @Primusa edited for clarification

Comment: What do you mean by "this conditional"?

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro If the output of A == (1, 0, 0) then feed the image into X.  If the output of B == (0, 1, 0) then feed the image into Y.  etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Tensorflow, `tf.case()` may be what you want, [see doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/case) for more information.

Here an example, supposing model Z should be used by default, and supposing the conditions are exclusive:

```python
condition_for_X = conditionX(output_A)  # e.g. tf.less(tf.reduce_sum(output_A), -1.) 
condition_for_Y = conditionX(output_A)  # e.g. tf.greater_equal(tf.reduce_sum(output_A), 1.) 

def use_X(): return model_X(output_A)
def use_Y(): return model_Y(output_A)
def use_Z(): return model_Z(output_A)
result = tf.case({condition_for_X: use_X, condition_for_Y : use_Y},
                  default=use_Z, exclusive=True)
```

Comment: Did'nt know tf.case exists. Can you use this for training/computing gradients?

Comment: It seems so, though one has to be careful with the behavior of tf.case() and tf.cond() - see for instance those issues: [unexpected tf.case behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42728235/tensorflow-why-is-tf-case-giving-me-the-wrong-result); [error when computing gradients with tf.cond](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/18007); etc.

Answer (score 1):

Reusing models is simple in keras using model.layers/input/ouput attribute.

If you want to pack everything into one model you could put X,Y and Z at the end of your first model. But every model will be calculated. However you could then insert a last layer a top of the output layers of X, Y, and Z which concatenate the layers and drop the output of two of these 3 models to zero based on the output of your first model.

Such a layer need the output of your 4 models as input and you would have to write the logic yourself.